# Confusion with 'Would"

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, deontic-vs-epistemic, protasis, will-would-meaning-wanting-to

What could be the possible meaning of the sentence?: "If you would agree to my conditions, I would give you compensation."

I would highly appreciate your response.

Comment: You should add some detail of what's confusing you about the sentence and why.

Comment: It's basically the same as "If you agree to my conditions I will give you compensation", but phrased as counterfactuals.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, does the sentence mean  "You are not willing, so I would not give you compensation."?

Comment: If you would please give us more detail, we might well be willing to answer you better. Are you confused by *would* in the *if* part because someone told you not to do that without explaining that it means if you are willing in a polite way?